# How to convert JSON Array to Javascript Object Array

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON value pushed from the server.

```
         result=[{"id":1492,"name":"Delhi"},
                 {"id":109,"name":"Coimbatore"},
                 {"id":576,"name":"Konni"},
                 {"id":525,"name":"Kottayam"}
                ]
```

I know how to convert JSON Array to Javascript Array.Here is the code below(got from stackoverflow)

```
        var locations = [];
        $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
            locations.push([obj.id,obj.name]);
        });
```

I want to convert this JSON Array to a JavaScript Object Array so that I can access the values as `jarray[0].id` which will give me the value 1492. Please advice

Comment: That's not a JSON array.  It's a JavaScript array.  JSON is a method of storing data as text.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything to the `result` array. Just use `result[0].id` and it will evaluate to `1492`.

Comment: Thank you. I believe I have to read the core javascript well again